# How to store Dictionary values in the database in the django restframework

Tags: database, django-rest-framework

Which field i  want to use in the django Restframework so that `i can store the data in  DB the way i specified below`. I am Using Django rest framework and djongo engine[MongoDB] to store it in the Database. I used ArrayModelField which doesn't match my expectation

```
"taxon": {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Rails",
                "pretty_name": "Brand -\u003e Rails",
                "permalink": "brand/rails",
                "parent_id": 2,
                "taxonomy_id": 2,
                "taxons": []
            }
```

Comment: And what is your expectation?

Comment: My expectation is to store the data's in the DB according to the format as I said above